# Loop through parallel child node

Tags: xml, xslt

From this:

```
  <CustomOffer_Children_Child_Birthdate>
     <DATA>2013-03-03</DATA>
     <DATA>2012-02-02</DATA>
     <DATA>2011-01-01</DATA>
  </CustomOffer_Children_Child_Birthdate>
  <CustomOffer_Children_Child_Age>
     <DATA>333</DATA>
     <DATA>222</DATA>
     <DATA>111</DATA>
  </CustomOffer_Children_Child_Age>
```

To this:

```
<Children>
   <Child>
     <Bithdate>2013-03-03</Bithdate>
     <Age>333</Age>
   </Child>
   <Child>
      <Bithdate>2012-02-02</Bithdate>
      <Age>222</Age>
</Child>
   <Child>
      <Bithdate>2011-01-01</Bithdate>
      <Age>111</Age>
   </Child>
</Children>
```

I tried to loop trough but I have no idea.

```
 <xsl:template match="fm:CustomOffer_Children_Child_Birthdate">
        <xsl:for-each select="fm:DATA">
            <Child>
                <Bithdate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()" />
                </Bithdate>
                <Age>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fm:CustomOffer_Children_Child_Age/fm:DATA/node()" />
                </Age>
            </Child>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

There must be a simple solution, but I don't get it.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please add the current results you get with what you have tried - to save people having to run what you have tried, wonder whether they get the results you are getting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without seeing the context. See if this could work for you:

```
<xsl:template match="fm:CustomOffer_Children_Child_Birthdate">
    <xsl:for-each select="fm:DATA">
        <Child>
            <Birthdate>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </Birthdate>
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <Age>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../fm:CustomOffer_Children_Child_Age/fm:DATA[$i]" />
            </Age>
        </Child>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

--
P.S. There's probably a better way to export your data (from Filemaker?).

Comment: Thanks, I just needed that hint. Works for me. But I have no idea how to export from filemaker in a better way... ?

Comment: @Querzel You should export from the child ("many") table instead of the parent ("one"). This is assuming you *have* a child table. If those are repeating fields, then you need to revise your structure.